# sympy print function to latex wihtout solving it

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I just started playing around with python `sympy`. For my own reference I'd like to convert functions to latex *as they are*, i.e. without `sympy` solving or rearranging them. Example:

```
ex711= (x**2 - 4*x + 3) / (x**2 + x - 2)
print(latex(limit(ex711, x, 1)))
```

Should return:

```
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{2} - 4 x + 3}{x^{2} + x - 2}
```

Instead it returns the result of the limit:

```
- \frac{2}{3}
```

Can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use capital 'L' Limit()

```
ex711= (x**2 - 4*x + 3) / (x**2 + x - 2)
print(latex(Limit(ex711, x, 1)))
```